# Angular prevent windows keyboard from appearing without 'readonly' attribute

Tags: angular, windows, typescript, keyboard, tablet

I'm trying to implement a functionality to use a physical keyboard or a virtual keyboard in a tablet depending on whether a SetButton component created by me is checked or not.

The problem is that **when clicking the input I need to NOT appear the windows keyboard, without using `readonly`**, because otherwise the cursor is not shown and the user can not select in the middle of a paragraph if you want to delete or modify something.

Since I don't have the `readonly` attribute, if I do the test in the tablet and touch the input field I get the windows keyboard, which I want to avoid.

**Does anyone know any way to avoid the windows keyboard without using the `readonly` attribute?**

Thanks in advance, any answer helps me.

Comment: have you tried this `<input [readOnly]="true">`

Comment: Maybe I haven't explained myself well, I don't want to see the windows keyboard WITHOUT using the ``readonly`` attribute

Comment: You can use  `<input [disabled]="true">`

Answer (score 0):

There is a property [readonly] for the `input`:

```
<input [readonly]="isReadOnly">
```

[Please, see this stackblitz example of readonly](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-readonly-input)

**UPDATE:**

```
<input [disabled]="!validate">
```

TypeScript:

```
validate = false;
```

Be careful, a disabled element is not editable and is not sent on submit.

**UPDATE 1:**

As an alternative, you can create two inputs which one input is hidden `visibility:hidden` to send data on `submit`:

```
<input [disabled]="!validate">
<input style="visibility:hidden">
```

Comment: Maybe I haven't explained myself well, I don't want to see the windows keyboard WITHOUT using the readonly attribute, thanks for your answer

Comment: If the disabled element is not sent on submit It's no use to me. I'm trying to execute blur() after focus() event and the windows keyboard appear and dissapear like a second after

Comment: I haven't tried your last post update, I finally found a "solution" by removing the tablet mode from the tablet in windows 10 and unchecking the option "Show touchpad when you are not in tablet mode and there is no keyboard connected".